# How to rename and extract all file?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, 7-zip

Looking for a .bat to rename and extract all.
The folder is `d:\EJ\%dd%-%mm%-%yyyy%\` (multiple files)

- K02699_ej.zip
- K02702_ej.zip
- K02703_ej.zip
- K02704_ej.zip
- K02705_ej.zip

Rename to

- K02699.zip
- K02702.zip
- K02703.zip
- K02704.zip
- K02705.zip

and then extract all

```
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=_" %%i in ('dir/b *_ej.zip') do ren %%i_%%j %%i.zip
for %%i in (*.zip) do 7z x %%i -o
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't see why it was so hard to figure out the minor changes you required:

```
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=_" %%i in ('dir/b *ej.zip') do ren %%i_%%j %%i.zip
for %%i in (*.zip) do 7z x %%i -o%%~ni
```

If you don't want to extract each archive to a separate sub-dir, just remove the -o argument.

Comment: Thank you very much. And i have more questions.
1. If i have a folder name is changing every day such as 
d:\EJ\27-12-2012\ (d:\EJ\%dd%-%mm%-%yyyy%\)
how to put a path in batch file?

Comment: Take a look at my answer [here](http://superuser.com/a/512489/138343).